# How is the approximation $\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}\approx \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}$ done?

Tags: derivatives, calculus

How is the approximation $\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}\approx \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}$ done? (suppose $k$ is an integer)

Is this a Taylor expansion?

(P.S. I asked this on Physics Stack Exchange because I encountered this in a physics textbook and I think approximations like this are probably only done in physics/engineering instead of mathematics)

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is just the first order approximation for $\sqrt{x}$. 2. Qmechanic is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approximation is valid for large $k\gg 1$.

Consider the small quantity $\frac{1}{k}\ll 1$. Then, by the binomial expansion:
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{k}}-1=\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^2\right)-1\approx\frac{1}{2k}$$
Multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{k}$, we have the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

One can see this by simply rationalising the numerator:
$$(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})\times\dfrac{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}~ \approx \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}$$

Since $\sqrt{k+1} \approx \sqrt{k}$ for sufficiently large $k$.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use derivatives to obtain this approximation: $$f(x) = \sqrt x \rightarrow f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$$
$$f(x+\delta x) - f(x) \approx f'(x).\delta x$$
$$f(x+1) - f(x) \approx \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}.1$$
$$ \sqrt {x+1} - \sqrt x \approx \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$$

provided $x \gg 1$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply Lagrange's theorem to $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ in the interval $[k,k+1]$, you get
$$
f(k+1)-f(k)=f'(\xi) (k+1-k),\quad \xi \in (k,k+1)
$$

i.e.,

$$
\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\xi}},\quad \xi \in (k,k+1)
$$

From this relation, you deduce that
$$
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k+1}} \leq \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}.
$$
This inequality holds for all $k\ge 1$, large or small.